# R Shiny DT responsive datatable height

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, responsive, dt

I am trying to have a full height datatable in Shiny that displays a number of rows according to available height, and number of pages changes as well.

The `DT` `responsive` extension is for width. Is it possible to have an equivalent for height?

An answer might be to modify the box on top `show N entries` by a new `N` value using javascript and some calculations on the maximum space that the table can take knowing the size of a row.

Here is a start:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Arbitrary component to remove space in the page"),

    dataTableOutput('table_name')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table_name <- DT::renderDataTable({
        data.frame(a=1:100, b = 100:1, c = 101:200)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a basic example of how change the number of rows in a table based on the window's height. It is not the most efficient way to do it, but works and can help you to create a better solution.

Please note that the delay to adjust the table should be tuned to your needs.

```R
jscode.autoHeightDT <- '
  autoHeightDT = function() {
    var offset = 100; // pixels used for other elements like title, buttons, etc

    // compute the number of rows to show in window
    var n = Math.floor(($(window).height() - offset) / $("#table_name tr").height());

    // set the new number of rows in table
    t = $("#table_name .dataTable").DataTable().page.len(n).draw();
  }

  // to adjust the height when the app starts, it will wait 0.8 seconds
  setTimeout(autoHeightDT, 800);

  // to react to changes in height of window 
  $(window).resize(function() {
    autoHeightDT();
  });

'

library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$script(jscode.autoHeightDT), # includes JavaScript code
    titlePanel("Arbitrary component to remove space in the page"),

    dataTableOutput('table_name')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table_name <- DT::renderDataTable({
        data.frame(a=1:100, b = 100:1, c = 101:200)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Note that the `show N entries` button is empty, not really a problem. I will wait to accept your answer as there might be a better solution, but this one is already really closed to what I need. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I edited the code for the offset variable. Thank you.